# Lineno package in latex causes warning message

Tags: packages, warnings, line-numbering, lineno

I'm trying to figure out why the line number package in latex causes a warning message. Once I add `lineno` package in my preamble, I receive the following message:

`./lineno.sty: LaTeX Warning: Command \@parboxrestore  has changed. Check if current package is valid.`

Have anyone received a similar message and if so how to solve it?

Many thanks for your comments!

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes} % US EN quotation marks
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\topmargin 0.02cm
\oddsidemargin 0.2cm
\textwidth 16cm 
\textheight 21cm
\footskip 1.0cm

\newenvironment{sciabstract}{%
\begin{quote}
\end{quote}}

\newcounter{lastnote}
\newenvironment{scilastnote}{%
\setcounter{lastnote}{\value{enumiv}}%
\addtocounter{lastnote}{+1}%
\begin{list}%
{\arabic{lastnote}.}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{.22in}}
{\setlength{\labelsep}{.5em}}}
{\end{list}}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\usepackage{setspace} %\singlespacing
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!20}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ulem} 

\usepackage{authblk}

\usepackage{titling}

\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}}
\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\large}
\postauthor{\par\end{flushleft}}
\predate{\begin{flushleft}}
\postdate{\par\end{flushleft}\vskip 0.5em}


\title{Internal affairs under the microscope of the Moon Department}

\author{\vspace{12pt} John Star}
\affil{Moon University, Moon}
\date{}


\begin{document} 
\linenumbers
\maketitle

\begin{sciabstract}
\small
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\
\onehalfspacing

\noindent
\textbf{Keywords:} bbbb,bbbb,bbbb,bbbb
\end{sciabstract}
\


\onehalfspacing
\section{Introduction}

cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

\end{document}
```

[image: PDF view]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem (with the offending package call). Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see "compilable" code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Done! MWE is included now

Comment: I placed both packages under `\postdate{\par\end{flushleft}\vskip 0.5em}` and deleted `hyperref` from where it was together with `lineno` but nothing changed. The warning message still appears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lineno` contains the line

```
\CheckCommand*\@parboxrestore{\@arrayparboxrestore\let\\\@normalcr}
```

which checks the definition of `\@parboxrestore` against its second argument. However, `csquotes` does

```
\appto\@parboxrestore{\blx@parboxrestore}
```

so the check will fail if `csquotes` is loaded before `lineno`.

The warning can be  thus avoided by loading `lineno` first and  `csquotes` afterwards. (Note that you are loading `csquotes`twice, and `hyperref` should be loaded last.)

Comment: I think, I solved the problem. The doubled use of the `csquotes`, which I haven't realized, and your suggestion of the order fixed the warning message. I changed the code above so that it works perfectly. Many thanks for your feedback.